# Determining whether a set of vectors is a subspace (given an equation with matrices?)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

So I have this question that I just don't know how to set up for my linear algebra class. It involves the concept of subspaces which is something I've struggled on in this class for sure, it would be very much appreciated if someone could explain it! Thanks!

> State whether the set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$. If it is not a
> subspace, explain why not and if it is a subspace, give a basis for
> it.
>
> a) Let $S_1$ be the set of vectors $\begin{bmatrix}
>      x \\
>      y \\
>     z \\  w \end{bmatrix}$ such that $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2\\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
>     x \\
>    y \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4\\ 0 & -3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
>      z \\
>      w \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

I have no idea how to start on this! Please help!

Comment: Start by multiplying everything out and getting a system of equations.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a subspace? Are you able to check whether the different parts of the definition apply to $S_1$?

Comment: @Greg Yea I do know them! I just didn't know how to even check those conditions, but the answer below explained it really well for me on how exactly to justify that it is the subspace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the system $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2\\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
   y \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4\\ 0 & -3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
     z \\
     w \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ we deduce that $3x+2y=z+4w$ and $x-y=-3w$. Then, a little algebra shows that $y= 3w+x$ and $z=2w+5x$. In other words, whenever $(x,y,z,w)\in S_1$, then $y= 3w+x$ and $z=2w+5x$. On the other hand, it is not difficult to see that if $x,w\in \mathbb{R}$, then $(x,3w+x,2w+5x,w)\in S_1$, i.e., $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2\\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
   3w+x \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4\\ 0 & -3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
     2w+5x \\
     w \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$ This shows that, for every $(x,y,z,w)\in \mathbb{R}^{4}$, $(x,y,z,w)\in S_1$ if and only if $y= 3w+x$ and $z=2w+5x$. Furthermore, the last two equations kind of tell us that every element of $S_1$ "depends" only on two variables.

With this in mind, it is natural to think that $S_1$ *is* a 2- dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Proving that $S_1$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ at this point should be very easy. You just have to argue now that it has dimension 2. This can be done in a number of ways, but I think a very elegant way to do it is to note that $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to S_1$ given by $f(x,w) = (x,3w+x,2w+5x,w)$ is a linear isomorphism (this is also simple). In particular, $\{f(1,0), f(0,1)\}$ is a basis for $S_1$.

Comment: Thank you that makes so much sense! By the time you answered this I had already done the first step (finding out that y=3w+x and z=2w+5x but that was all i managed to figure out. The explanation for how the basis is formed and why it would be dimension of 2 was great! Again, thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, apparently I can't cast a vote because my account is too new :(

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I was able to help you. Don't worry about the vote, what matters is that we managed to solve the problem together.